# Power Plant - solve the problem in O(nlogn)

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I had the following problem on the exam: A certain power plant needs coal to operate, so it has ordered `n` deliveries, and information about each delivery (number of tons) is stored in a list `A`. The delivered coal is stored in warehouses with consecutive numbers 0, 1, .... (Their exact number is not given). Each warehouse has the same capacity in tons given by the number `T` (where `T>=A[i]` for `i=0,1,...,n-1`). There are a few rules for storing coal. Coal cannot be split, that is, each shipment must be allocated to only one warehouse. In addition, we always try to put coal into the warehouse with the smallest possible number. The problem is to find the warehouse number where we store the last (`n-1`) delivery.

For Example:

```
A = [1, 6, 2, 10, 8, 3, 1]
T = 10
```

The answer is 0.

Solving O(n^2) of this problem is pretty obvious, but I have no idea how this task could be solved in O(nlogn), and that's the complexity you could get the most points for. Any ideas?

Comment: `log n` is the complexity of binary search. So `n log n` is the complexity if you do a binary search during each iteration. Does that point you in the right direction?

Comment: I thought about using binary search, but for that I need to have a sorted list, and after all, I can't sort the list ```A```

Comment: You can create a list of tuples `(capacity, original_index)` and keep that sorted by capacity

Comment: I know this but after all, sorting the list will only complicate things more, how using binary search should I now determine which shipment will go to which warehouse? I can't imagine it

Comment: Because when I sort A it then messes up the order of delivery

Comment: My thinking was that you can use binary search to find the warehouse whose capacity is closest to the shipment size.

Comment: Well, let's say we create a zero-filled list B of length n (because we certainly don't need more). This list stands for all the warehouses. How should the binary search on this list look like, under what condition will we go to the left/right sublist? Well, and once we find a place and add the supply to the corresponding place in B, then B will not be sorted. And why are we sorting A in that case? Unless you mean using binary search on A, but then how does that relate to finding the right warehouse?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried to solve this problem myself. I was just passing on my thoughts to help you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the best to have sorted arrays by the remaining capacities of the non-empty warehouses. A binary search would find the possible warehouses in O(logN) as all leaves greater than A[i] would be candidates. However I don't see any possibility to fulfill the second condition (the warehouse with the smallest has to be chosen) below O(N) in worst case.